# iOS how to put shadow on scrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, shadow

In my iOS app

my application contains scrollview and i want to put a shadow and i have tried lot of codes but none of them are working..

i have programatically taken scrollview

[self.view addsubview:scroll1];

want to set shadow on scrollview using slider

so if anyone know then answer it....

```
-(IBAction)slide3changed:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider=(UISlider*)sender;

    scroll1.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    scroll1.layer.shadowRadius = slider.value;
    scroll1.layer.shadowOpacity = slider.value;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to set **`masksToBounds`**:

```
-(IBAction)slide3changed:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider=(UISlider*)sender;

    scroll1.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    scroll1.layer.shadowRadius = slider.value;
    scroll1.layer.shadowOpacity = slider.value;
    scroll1.layer.masksToBounds = NO; // This is important
}
```

Comment: When i add imageview on scrollview....then i add that scrollview in view1 after that i am adding to main view...                                                              then i provide shadow on view but problem is that it shadows are applying to also image but i want to only apply shadow on only view......so reply as soon as possible....

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to set the offset as well for the shadow to start appearing.

```
scroll1.layer.masksToBounds = NO; // this default
scroll1.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
scroll1.layer.shadowOpacity = slider.value;
scroll1.layer.shadowRadius = slider.value;
scroll1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: but then subviews will float around

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to achieve the same and the given solution here did not work for me. Namely the scroll view that used paging, though nested in the view controller (frame 35, 80, 250, 447), did not render properly. What I did was to add the scroll view in a simple uiview and used the following code:

```
self.scrollViewContainer.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.scrollViewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2f;
self.scrollViewContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 20);
self.scrollViewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.scrollViewContainer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure that the outside edges of your scrollView are visible inside the superView? If the scrollView goes all the way to the edges of the superView then the shadow would be offscreen and therefore not visible.

shadowOpacity is a float value from 0.0 to 1.0 so make sure that your slider min and max are set to 0.0 and 1.0 respectively.

Also, I don't think you want to change the shadowRadius like you are. You can probably just leave that property alone until you get this working.

You also might try changing the shadowOffset property to make sure the shadow is pointing in the direction(s) that you want.